# SQL Server parse JSON to update another table

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json, json-value

I have a table with JSON data in one of the columns and i'm trying to parse the JSON data and insert into a temp table

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE
( 
     ID INT, 
     Status NVARCHAR(50), 
     Cost DECIMAL(20, 0)
)


INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE
    SELECT 
        ID, 
        JSON_VALUE(mydata, '$.Status') AS Status,
        JSON_VALUE(mydata, '$.Cost') AS Cost 
    FROM Expense
```

I get this error:

> Error Converting data type nvarchar to numeric

The same works fine if I comment out the `Cost` column.

Sample JSON data in Cost table

```
 | ID | mydata 
 +----+-------------------------------------
 | 1  | {"Status":"Shipped","Cost":"$10.50"}
```

Comment: Just curious why decimal(20,0) and not decimal(20,2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the value to MONEY.  It is a little more forgiving than decimal()

**Example**

```
Declare @Expense Table ([ID] int,mydata varchar(50))
Insert Into @Expense Values 
 (1,'{"Status":"Shipped","Cost":"$10.50"}')
 
SELECT ID
      ,JSON_VALUE(mydata,'$.Status') as Status
      ,try_convert(money,JSON_VALUE(mydata,'$.Cost'))  as Cost 
 FROM @Expense
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Status  Cost
1   Shipped 10.50
```

Comment: Thanks but the result comes out as $10 and not $10.50

Comment: @RData As I commented in your question, your table variable has decimal(20,0) not decimal(20,2)  The (20,0) is zero decimal places

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to cast the string into a decimal value, give the following a try:

```
DECLARE @TEMPTABLE
( ID INT , Status nvarchar(50), Cost DECIMAL(20,0))


INSERT INTO @TEMPTABLE
(
    ID,
    Status,
    Cost
)
SELECT 
    ID, 
    JSON_VALUE(mydata,'$.Status') AS [Status],
    TRY_CAST(REPLACE(JSON_VALUE(mydata,'$.Cost'), '$', '') AS DECIMAL(20,0)) AS [Cost]
FROM Expense
```

Comment: Returning NULL value

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to remove the "$" money symbol from the string before the cast. It should work now.